# SOAP - Prefix without namespace

Tags: java, soap, namespaces, prefix

this is what I want:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tps="http://mysite.it">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tps:getBook>
         <tps:id>45</tps:id>
      </tps:Retrieve_getBook_Poi_Recordset>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but this is I have:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tps="http://mysite.it">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tps:getBook xmlns:tps="http://mysite.it">
         <tps:id xmlns:tps="http://mysite.it">45</tps:id>
      </tps:Retrieve_getBook_Poi_Recordset>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I'm using javax.xml.soap.* to create soap message...and I cannot find a method to insert only prefix in param tag.

this is the code to generate soap message:

```
MessageFactory msgFactory = null;
SOAPMessage message = null;
msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
message = msgFactory.createMessage();
SOAPEnvelope messageEnvelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPBody messageBody = messageEnvelope.getBody();

messageEnvelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(PREFIX, getNameSpace(method));

SOAPElement soapMethod = messageBody.addChildElement(method, PREFIX);
SOAPElement param = soapMethod.addChildElement("id",PREFIX);
param.addTextNode("45");
```

what can I do to remove only namespace?

Comment: The xml you posted is not well-formed. Anyway, try to replace _messageBody.addChildElement(method, PREFIX);_ with _messageBody.addChildElement(envelope.createName(method, PREFIX, getNameSpace(method)));_

Comment: thank's for your help...mhhmh..na!....it's the same -_-'....

Answer (score 1):

For Element and Attribute nodes:

```
Node node = ...;
String name = node.getLocalName();
```

will give you the local part of the node's name.

As you have mentioned, you really don't want to strip namespace info from your XML. This is a good workaround for your particular case, but I would leave the namespace info intact.